# WPF combobox does not show values at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I am a newbie with WPF.
I have a combobox bound to an XML datasource defined in the Window.Resources.

The combobox values are shown in the designer, but it comes out empty at runtime.

Am I missing something here.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfExample4.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData">
            <x:XData>
                <customers>
                    <customer name="Customer 1">
                        <order desc="Big Order">
                            <orderDetail product="Glue" quantity="21" />
                            <orderDetail product="Fudge" quantity="32" />
                        </order>

                    </customer>
                    <customer name="Customer 2">
                        <order desc="First Order">
                            <orderDetail product="Mousetrap" quantity="4" />
                        </order>
                        </customer>

                    </customers>
            </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
        </Window.Resources>

            <Grid DataContext= "{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}, XPath=customers/customer}" Margin="4" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- CUSTOMERS -->
                <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Customers" />
                    <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DockPanel>
        </Grid>

    </Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add namespace to root element ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

*Note:*

> The root node of the XML data has an xmlns attribute that sets the XML
>   namespace to an empty string. This is a requirement for applying XPath
>   queries to a data island that is inline within the XAML page. In this
>   inline case, the XAML, and thus the data island, inherits the
>   System.Windows namespace. Because of this, you need to set the
>   namespace blank to keep XPath queries from being qualified by the
>   System.Windows namespace, which would misdirect the queries.

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData">
        <x:XData>
            <customers xmlns="">
                <customer name="Customer 1">
                    <order desc="Big Order">
                        <orderDetail product="Glue" quantity="21" />
                        <orderDetail product="Fudge" quantity="32" />
                    </order>
                </customer>
...
```